# Extract part of a line upto a particular string

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

Let us assume I have a file with lines like:

```
/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/opt
/java/jre/jre_jvm/bin/opt
/foo/bar/bin/other/stuff/here
```

Is there a way I can extract part of the lines upto `bin`. I mean, assume those lines are at `file.txt` then

```
$ <some_command> file.txt 
/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/
/java/jre/jre_jvm/bin/
/foo/bar/bin/
```

Comment: Does all lines in the file has only one `/bin` in it? What happens if you had a line like `/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/opt/bin`?

Answer (score 8):

There are many ways to do this. Here are some:

```
# greedily caputure up to the last slash
grep -o '.*/bin/' file.txt
```

```
# remove all non-slash chars from the end of each line
sed 's#\(/bin/\).*$#\1#' file.txt
```

```
# using slash as a delimiter, blank out the last field
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "bin") {NF=i; break}} 1' file.txt
```

Comment: I just wanted the total part but only upto bin/ ... I dont want whats there after bin/... and sometimes no guarantee that /bin/opt just, it may be /bin/opt/some/part. Please consider this case too

Comment: Gotcha, missed that requirement.

Answer (score 4):

A pure bash way:

```
while read -n line
do
    [[ $line =~ /bin/ ]] && printf "%s\n" "${line/%\/bin\/*//bin/}"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

What, no Perl?

```
perl -ne 's#/bin\K.*## && print' file
```

If you know that *all* lines contain the pattern you want, you can simplify to:

```
perl -pe 's#/bin\K.*##' file
```

The `\K` is a PCRE expression that means "ignore everything before the `\K`".

---

You can also do things like

```
awk -F"/bin" '{print $1FS}' file
```

That sets awk's field delimiter (`FS`) to `/bin`, and then prints the first field and the value of `FS` (which is `/bin`). That one, again, assumes you want every line. If not, use this one instead:

```
awk -F"/bin" '($2){print $1FS}' file
```

Comment: Indeed Perl was missing. choosing `#` as a regex delimiter is also a good practice with paths patterns. +1

Answer (score 3):

In python:

```py
python3 -c "for l in open('f').readlines(): print(l[:l.find('/bin')+5])"

/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/
/java/jre/jre_jvm/bin/
```

where f is the path to the file (in single quotes).

Comment: awesome but I would love that if its in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Along with other good answers, you can also try the following which will make sure whatever there is after `/bin/`, will not be printed:

```
grep -Po ".*/(?<=/bin/)" file
```

Example:

```
$ cat test_file 
/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/opt
/java/jre/jre_jvm/bin/opt/home

$ grep -Po ".*/(?<=/bin/)" test_file 
/java/jdkxx/jvm_jdk/bin/
/java/jre/jre_jvm/bin/
```

Here we are using the [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) with positive lookbehind `(?<=/bin/)` to make sure that we take only upto the `/`, where we have `/bin/` at last.

Comment: This looks very promising to me

Comment: That looks distinctly odd to me. Lookaheads are supposed to be zero width, they shouldn't appear in the matched output. Wait. Those are lookbehinds. Ah. Rather convoluted. Glen's way is much better.

Comment: @muru Let my try all the commands at home PC , office PC I cant do all this.

Comment: Note that this will also match on lines that do not contain `/bin`. For example `This is a rubbish bin`. Also, I don't see the point of the lookbehind. What does it offer that `grep -Po '.*bin/'` doesn't?

Comment: @terdon: The lookbehind pattern is `bin/`, i think this won't match `This is a rubbish bin`..i think you probably meant `This is a rubbish bin/`..in that case i will modify the answer (Please correct me if i am wrong)....i have posted it as another way that can use lookarounds, might be helpful in some other similar cases..you are absolutely right, it won't give any extra benefit in this case than what you have mentioned..

Comment: Yes, I did indeed mean `rubbish bin/` and the new version deals with that one correctly.